# Computer powers back on after shutting down

Tags: 20.04, shutdown, ssd, 20.10, sata

I'm running Ubuntu 20.10 now, this issue existed on 20.04 as well, but when I send the shutdown command through any means my computer turns back on after about a 1 second similar to a reboot.

I tested with two SSD's as I have one 1 TB that just has Windows 10 and my second SSD is a 500 GB with just Ubuntu, it's a straight simple default install for both. I don't go back and forth much so I don't dual boot because I didn't want to mess with that, but when I want to switch I physically change the power and SATA cable to the SSD and the other is totally unplugged.

I plugged in my Windows 10 SSD and the reboot problem was not there, it stayed shutdown. When I switched to the Ubuntu SSD, it came back. They are both Samsung EVO SSD's so they are about as similar as they get albeit my 1 TB is larger and a faster model.

I've checked my cables and they all seem fine, and it only happens when my Ubuntu SSD is plugged in. When I tried looking around the internet, I couldn't really find someone with a similar issue, but possible my search skills are lacking on this topic.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Check in the BIOS if "wake on LAN" is on (set it off). Do still have this  problem if you enter sudo shutdown -h 0 in the terminal (It is not a solution, but it can help to pinpoint the problem)

Comment: You could look at the logs with `sudo journalctl  --since="-30 minutes"`. Adjust the interval to cover the last event.

Comment: @BernardDecock the PC still booted back up after the **sudo shutdown -h 0** however after looking at my BIOS for a WOL related featured, I disable something to do with booting from LAN and it seemed to work and now the computer stays shutdown. I do not understand why it would wake back up anyways when Windows never did this. What could be causing a WOL request?

Comment: @N_mag Maybe WOL is disabled in Win10? https://www.groovypost.com/howto/enable-wake-on-lan-windows-10/